# How to generate a range of values between a min and max with a set amount of increments in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets I have listed my vertical axis with 10-bit code values. From 0 to 1023. I would like to assign 16-bit code values (from 0 to 65535) aside 10-bit code values. So instead of creating 65535 rows to distribute a perfect range from 0 to 65535, I would instead like to distribute 0 to 65535 across 10-bit code values (0 to 1023).

So in other words list a range from 0 (min) to 65535 (max) in 1023 increments. With the 1023 increment being 65535. The formula would have to be written for a single cell then I'd just copy it across the entire y-axis range to generate all the values between 0 and 65535 across all 10-bit increments.

How can I do this in google sheets?

Comment: Please show a small table that illustrates your expected result.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot go from `0` to `65535` in `1024` steps where every step would increment the value by an equal integer, because the required step size would be `65535 / 1024 ≈ 63.9990` which is not an integer.

What you *can* do is go from `0` to **`65472`** in `1024` equal integer steps. The step size is exactly `64` and the last value is `64` shy of `65536`:

```
=sequence(2^10, 1, 0, 2^16 / 2^10)
```

To go from `0` to `65536` in *`1025`* equal integer steps, use this:

```
=sequence(2^10 + 1, 1, 0, 2^16 / 2^10)
```

More generally, to get a sequence that starts at `0` and increments **evenly** until `65535`, allowing fractional steps when necessary, use this:

```
=let( 
  start, 0, 
  end, 65535, 
  numValues, 1024, 
  step, (end - start) / (numValues - 1), 
  arrayformula(sequence(numValues, 1, 0) * step) 
)
```